# Mask User url with dynamic temprorary user

Tags: users, uri

Is there a module to mask user url with a temporary url which only last for a day and next time it generates another url for the same user?

I want to hide the users UID/username so that no two users can talk to each other but can view their profiles with a temporary url.

I checked with pathauto module but it generates a dynamic permanent url not a temporary ones.

Edit:- 
I used [uuid_link](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_link) module for this and ran cron to generate uuid for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unlikely; this sounds like a very specific use-case that wouldn't need a dedicated project. You're going to have to implement your own custom module to pull this off.

You could go an aliasing route in a manner similar pathauto but that is likely to leave source paths open (e.g. **user/XXX**) to accessibility. A better approach is to create a simple module that:

1. Uses a [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) implementation to generate random hash to UID mappings periodically and storing them in custom table.
2. Implementing a [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to generate a dynamic path like `user/%random_hash` that maps the random hash paths in #1 to a user profile page (generated in the the same manner like [`user/%user`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/user/user.module?h=7.x#n1785))

Comment: yes I took this approach. I was thinking that there was already a dedicated module for this requirement.